# Pandas, hdf and pickle on colab

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, hdf5

I am trying to load an hdf file created by pandas on my local python 3.10, but I am getting

```
desc = pd.read_hdf(hfile,"descriptions")

...


ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
```

I search on StackOverflow, and this sort of error seems to be common. The suggested fix is

```
pip install pickle5
import pickle5 as pickle
```

But this does not work here. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you are using the `pip` specific to your python. For instance I call `python3` in the command line, so to install a package I use `python3 -m pip install ...` whereas `pip install` would install the package for python 2. A common mishap so I figured I would mention it.

Comment: @Allie I have been using just plain `pip` in colab for years, and it had never failed to install into the right python.